# Javascript: change actives navigation link color via JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i am working on this [website](http://weierweg-liestal.ch/home/)  (Builted via Wordpress) and i want to change, **only in this page**, the color of the active Links in the navigation into #000000 (the links with the red borders).

How can i do it via JS? I tried via CSS but does not works...

I tried:

CSS:

```
.page-id-19 .menu-item-190 { color: #000000; }

.page-id-19 .menu-item-191 { color: #000000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

All link black:

```
 .page-id-19 .menu-item a {
        color: #000000 !important;
    }
```

The 'Home':

```
#menu-item-189 a {
    color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: @N_A you must put it at the end of style.css (I have update the code now)